# Raspberry Pi boot problems after edit fstab on other Linux

Tags: linux, boot, raspberry-pi

on my Raspberry Pi I have a SD card with noobs and an installed Raspbian. Everything went fine without any problems, it was booted directly into the raspbian. Now I made a wrong entry in the fstab and booting was no longer possible. "root locked unable to mount /mnt/server...". kind of like that, anyway. Now I put the SD in a laptop with Linux mint and commented out the wrong line with sudo nano /etc/fstab. Back to my RPi now the recoverymenu of noobs comes with "select an os to boot" but the window is empty. Even when enforcing Recovery (Shift key), it no longer recognizes that Raspbian is installed. Before editing fstab, he had recognized this.

Is there any way to fix that? like fixmbr to boot directly into the raspbian?
I'm afraid I don't know Linux so well.

Comment: It's all part of the linux learning process - I would never edit fstab on another machine, only the machine it's meant for- Just rewrite the SD and start again.

Comment: please don't.... I had a prosody server up and running.
Isn't there another option? from windows I know the "overinstall" so that only the system files are replaced.

Comment: ALWAYS make a backup copy 'sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak in future

Comment: that was a lesson to me. will make a backup for all changes to files. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it: The problem was a corrupted file in the `SETTINGS` mount point. There is a file called: `installed_os.json`. This one was defective. For whatever reason. As a result, NOOB's could not find any installed Linux and so the selection window remained empty. The following content had to be in my case included:

```
[
 {
  "description" : "A Debian wheezy port, optimised for the Raspberry Pi",
  "folder" : "/mnt/os/Raspbian",
  "icon" : "/mnt/os/Raspbian/Raspbian.png",
  "name" : "Raspbian",
  "partitions" : [
"/dev/mmcblk0p6",
"/dev/mmcblk0p7"
  ],
  "release_date" : "2014-01-07"
 }
]
```

now NOOB's knew about an already installed linux and was able to boot without any problems.